# random color changing using javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Homework</title>
        
        <script>
        
            function first()    {
                document.getElementById('type1').style.position = 'absolute';
                document.getElementById('type1').style.left= "100px";
                document.getElementById('type1').style.top= "200px";
                var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
                var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
                var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

                var newColor = "rgb("+ red + "," + green + "," + blue +")";
            }
            
            function second()   {
                document.getElementById('type1').style.position = 'absolute';
                document.getElementById('type1').style.left= "0px";
                document.getElementById('type1').style.top= "80px";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Special Button</h1>
        
        <input id = 'type1' type = 'button' value = 'Click' onclick = 'output();'
                            onmouseover= 'first()' onmouseout= 'second()';' />
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get the button to change to random colors every time you hover over it but I can't seem to get it to work, If anybody knows how, please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kevin, do you mean to be moving the position of the button on mouse over?

Comment: No, but for the button to change to random colors every time you hover over it. example: starts off as white but once you hover over it, it changes to black and so on.

Comment: Aron's answer is accurate, you never assign the color to the element. But keep in mind that querying the DOM incurs a cost so when possible store references to the elements you need to manipulate and try to batch the changes to avoid repeated repaints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is assign the color to a style property. In this case the background color of the button.

```
function first() {
  var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  var newColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
  document.getElementById("type1").style.backgroundColor = newColor;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome :) If it solved your problem please can you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your homework to look like you copied it from the internet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Button Homework</title>
    <style>
      #type1{
        position: absolute;}

      #type1.mouseover{
        left: 100px;
        top: 200px;}

      #type1:not(.mouseover){
        left: 0px;
        top: 80px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Special Button</h1>
    <input id="type1" onclick="Output()" onmouseover="MouseOver(this)" onmouseout="MouseOut(this)" type="button" value="click">
    <script>
      function MouseOver(button) {
         button.classList.add('mouseover');
         //set backgroundColor to random hex string
         button.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
       }

       function MouseOut(button) {
         button.classList.remove('mouseover');
       }

       function Output() {
         //whatever this does
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that moving the buttons location triggers a mouseout event, so it gets pretty crazy. `<style>` doesn't seem to apply when you put it inline in the snippet.